# What is the Precession direction of positron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, precession

In Larmor precession; The spin angular momentum of an electron precesses counter-clockwise about the direction of the magnetic field(An electron has a negative charge, so the direction of its magnetic moment is opposite to that of its spin).

But What is the larmor precession direction of a positron(anti-electron)?

Answer (score 1):

Compared to an electron the positron's magnetic moment and angular momentum have the opposite relationship. Therefore the precession will be in the opposite direction. In other words, a positron will precess clockwise about the magnetic field.

Note that the direction of the precession is given by the sign of the magnetic moment. [The electron and the positron have opposite magnetic moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_an_electron). Also, the fact that the electron and positron have opposite magnetic moments is [one of the most precise predictions of the standard model](https://www.mdpi.com/2218-2004/7/2/45/pdf).

Comment: The positron angular momentum and magnetic moment are in the same direction, but why that mean that the precession direction will be opposite? do you have any reference or paper that support your answer

Comment: The Nucleus of N15(positively charged) precess in the same direction as an electron

Comment: Added references